# Select rows based on matching a column contents across all rows within an identifier in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

Running SQL Server 14.0.2037.2 on Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H1

I am trying to return IDs only when another columns entry across all rows within that ID matches the entries of a similar column in a second table, again within specific IDs.
For example,

```
create table #F(patentid VARCHAR(8), subclass VARCHAR(3));

insert into #F values ('l','x');
insert into #F values ('l','y');
insert into #F values ('l','z');

insert into #F values ('m','x');

insert into #F values ('n','z');


create table #P(patentid VARCHAR(8), subclass VARCHAR(3));


insert into #P values ('b','x');

insert into #P values ('c','w');
insert into #P values ('c','x');
insert into #P values ('c','y');
insert into #P values ('c','z');

insert into #P values ('d','x');
insert into #P values ('d','y');
insert into #P values ('d','z');

insert into #P values ('e','x');
insert into #P values ('e','y');
insert into #P values ('e','z');
```

I am trying to write a query that will return, for each  patentid in #F, all patentIDs in #P where the subclass entries match exactly.
This true for "l" in #F that matches with "d" and "e" in #P [the matching subclasses are 'x', 'y' and 'z']
as well as for "m" in #F that matches with "b" in #P [the matching subclass is "x"]

the output should be:

```
l, d
l, e
m, b
```

The code needs to be efficient as both #F and #P contain millions of rows. I have tried Union, but that works with entire sets of rows and doesn't allow matching by a subset (i.e. within a patentid)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This might help: -- What you want is a join where the number of items in the source matches the number of items in the joined table and matches the number of items in the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an example of [Relational Division Without Remainder](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=714c71b1d10de5d486a3ce669bfc6a70), with multiple divisors**.

In other words you want to divide (in a relational sense) `#F` by `#P` and only take results where there is no remainder.

There are many solutions, here is one

- Partition both tables by `patentid` and calculate a windowed count
- Left join one table to the other by `subclass`, filtering against exact matching counts
- Group by pairs of IDs
- Filter out anything which doesn't have every `f.subclass` with a matching `p.subclass`, we do this with `HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.subclass)` because `COUNT(p.subclass)` only counts non-nulls.

```sql
SELECT
  f.patentid, p.patentid
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f.patentid)
    FROM #F f
) f
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.patentid)
    FROM #P p
) p ON p.cnt = f.cnt AND p.subclass = f.subclass
GROUP BY
  f.patentid, p.patentid
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.subclass);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=714c71b1d10de5d486a3ce669bfc6a70)

Comment: This is great and worked perfectly.  Thank you so much @Charlieface ! I learnt something today.. (partitioning selects sets of rows..)

Answer (score 0):

Is this efficient enough for you?

```
select f.patentId, p.patentid 
from (
    select patentId, STRING_AGG(subclass,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY subclass ASC) as class 
    from #F 
    group by patentId
) f
inner join (
    select patentId, STRING_AGG(subclass,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY subclass ASC) as class 
    from #P 
    group by patentId
) p on f.class = p.class
```

Comment: A good answer explains how it works, in addition to providing working code.

Comment: this does not work -- this will give multiple results for m since x is in many groups -- you also have to check the counts (as I said in my comment)